# When to disconnect MQTT service on an Android app which doesn't required MQTT on background

Tags: java, android, android-service, mqtt, paho

I'm using Paho-Mqtt client on my current Android project to get live feeds from the server. According to my requirement, I only need MQTT service while the app is on the foreground. And every screen of the application linked to different mqtt-topics. Example:

```
If user in Activity A, I need to subscribe to a MQTT topic A.  
If your move to Activity B I need to unsubscribe from topic A and subscribe to topic B.
```

Now the question here is, when should I connect to MQTT service and when should I disconnect?

1. I can connect (& subscribe) to MQTT service in onResume() function of
   each activity and (unscubscribe &) disconnect onPause() function.

Otherwise,

2. I can connect to MQTT service in onCreate() function of Application
   So, I can keep the client connected throughout the application and
   do the subscribe & unsubscribe during the individual activity's
   onResume()/onPause() functions.

**Both ways are horrible**, especially the second way where there is no way to disconnect the MQTT service while app no longer in the foreground. Because there is no straightforward way to handle the events of an Android App's going background or getting terminated.

Can anybody give me suggestions to handle this in a best possible way?

Comment: [Firebase push notifications](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) (do not expect your backround service being able to keep connection - since Android Oreo) and [Websockets](https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-websocket-client) instead of MQTT (because of firewalls) is what you need ;-)

Comment: I don't want to keep my connection alive in the background forever but need to keep it alive during the time app is in the foreground (throughout all the activities).

Comment: The modern architecture is a **single activity** and multiple fragments (or recently: multiple views).

Comment: Problem is each of these MQTT dependent activities already has their own fragments(Tab-styled / Navigation drawers). Therefore that approach won't be the best for my case.

Comment: Nothing personal, but I wonder why is your question upvoted. You should split the problems you are trying to solve in [separate clear questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also provide the code you have already tried.

Answer (score 1):

Two approached for this:

1. You can have a MQTTClient in every Activity and handle that client 'inside' your activity.
2. Or, and this is a more resource friendly approach, you create a background Service where you put your MQTTClient.

You still need to subscribe and unsubscribe in the onResume() onPause().
The same as you also would use a BroadcastReceiver or Events.

If you want to have better control over the states of your lifecycle check out the Lifecycle.Events:
[Handling Lifecycles with Lifecycle-Aware Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle.html)

Use it to execute sub or unsub.

```
@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME)
public void connectListener() {
    ...
}
```

Also check out [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid) which might helps you also in your solution finding.

Good luck.

Comment: According to your second approach, when should I kill/stop that background Service which handles my MQTT connection?

Comment: If this MQQT service is used quite often, then you create this service, use it and thats it (no start stop stuff - it will run in the background). You might wanna look into this first: 
https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html
Hope it helps in your decision to create a service - because i do not  know much what exactly your use case is.